# Should a link 'has one' or 'belongs_to' a category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, one-to-many

I'm designing a simple Rails app with 2 models: `Link` and `Category`. Each link has exactly one category, and a category can have 0 or multiple links. What association should I apply to `Link` and `Category`? I'm very new to Ruby and those association terms are so confused to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said `each link has exactly one category`

```
class Link < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

category should exist before the link, so we go for `belongs_to`, not `has_one`

You said `a category can have 0 or multiple links`, so 0, 1, 2 or 79.

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :links
end
```

Comment: Well, I see a `has_one` hiding in _"each link **has** exactly **one** category"_, so it might not be that obvious why it has to be `belongs_to` and not `has_one` on the `Link` side. What do you mean by _"category should exist before the link"_?

Comment: A belongs_to because link contains the foreign key to the category table

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest first to read [active record associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations)

In your case

```
class Link
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category
  has_many :links
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't get confused by the semantics when it gets to `has_one` and `belongs_to`.

The key difference is that `belongs_to` puts the foreign key on **this**  models table:

```
class Link < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :links
end
```

You should read `belongs_to :category` as "this models table has a category_id column that references categories, it can only belong to a single category".

If you instead used:

```
class Link < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :category
end
```

Rails would attempt to resolve the association through the `categories.link_id` column which won't work at all. `has_one` should be used when you have a one to one association on the the side without the foreign key:

```
class Country
  has_one :capitol
end

class Capitol
  belongs_to :country
end
```